# BayesSearchCV parameters

Tags: scikit-learn, bayesian, hyperparameters, scikit-optimize

I just read about `Bayesian optimization` and I want to try it.

I installed `scikit-optimize` and checked the API, and I'm confused:

1. I read that Bayesian optimization starts with some initialize samples.

   - I can't see where I can change this number ? (`BayesSearchCV`)
   - `n_points` will change the number of parameter settings to sample in parallel and `n_iter` is the number of iterations (and if I'm not wrong the iterations can't run in parallel, the algorithm improve the parameters after every iteration)
2. I read that we can use different acquisition functions.
   I can't see where I can change the acquisition function in `BayesSearchCV` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something you are looking for?

```
BayesSearchCV(..., optimizer_kwargs={'n_initial_points': 20, 'acq_func': 'gp_hedge'}, ...)
```

[skopt.Optimizer](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/modules/generated/skopt.Optimizer.html) is the one actually doing the hyperparameter optimization.

`BayesSearchCV` will build `Optimzier` with `optimizer_kwargs` parameters.

https://github.com/scikit-optimize/scikit-optimize/blob/de32b5fd2205a1e58526f3cacd0422a26d315d0f/skopt/searchcv.py#L551